# Switching to new application version by web.config

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

Is it a good idea to switch new application version by changing web.config?

I have an ASP.NET core application running on an IIS server. But I cannot access the IIS server directly, I need to put the application files to share folder and wait for a program (something like rsync) to copy the application files to IIS server. If I take the [normal deployment process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/app-offline), it has a long downtime.

To reduce the downtime, I put new application files in a subfolder and update application path in web.config. It was tested in VM, but I don't know if it a good idea. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

[image: My Application folder structure]

Comment: there must be some technique with IIS to help reduce the downtime as much as possible. I've personally never had to deal with such an issue. But really `IIS` is becoming the past, there will be things like `docker` evolve quickly and fast in the future, that will replace `IIS` in many aspects including reducing the downtime when deploying. You can consider that option of using `docker` for deploying your asp.net core app. With basic settings (don't require any extra framework or platform), your app's downtime can reduce to the time of restarting a docker service which can be just 1-5 seconds.

Comment: Yes, docker has lot of advantages. But I can't change the environment :(